# Should a UIView be swapped out or a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uikit

If it is a simple app where a user type in any user's name, and click "Go", and that user's public info on the server will then be displayed, I wonder if it is a best practice to swap out the `UIView` or the whole `UIViewController` be swapped out?

It is a label or banner of the app at the top of the screen, with a text box to type in any user's id, and a "Go" button.  When a user types in any user name and tap "Go", there should be an activity indicator (the spinning wheel), and then an asynchronous thread go fetch the data, and when done, the user name text box and the "Go" button will get swapped out by the user's public info.  The app's label or banner actually stays at the top of the screen the whole time. (which is 25% of the screen)

Will it be a best practice just to swap out a subview, or is it a best practice if a whole ViewController is swapped out? (either way, probably best with animation for the transition).  What if the app is to be extended by other functionalities and screens later on?  (by the way, it seems that if by UIView, then `[UIView transitionWithView: ...]` can be used, while by `UIViewController`, then `presentViewController:animated` will be best to handle them?)

Comment: You should have a close look at UINavigationController's documentation.

Comment: thanks.  what if the app doesn't want this stack of view controllers feel, but what the "freely" jumping to any view feel?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no clear "best practice" for this case really. It is more a matter of how you want to structure the navigation and general user experience in your app. Sometimes it makes sense to push a new ViewController and sometimes switching Views make sense.

From my experience it can be quite a hassle to manage several completely different views from the same ViewController, especially if you want some neat transitions and custom appearance. (I mean "views" as in a screen full of content, where the views have completely different purposes like the textfield with "Go"-button and the info-section etc)

I would suggest you push a new ViewController for it. Especially if there might be new features or new ways of presenting user-information later on. I would also suggest presenting the activity indicator on the page with the "Go"-button, and make sure the user isn't moved back and forth unless there is actual information to be displayed.

Another solution could be to present that banner (which sounds fairly large at 25% of the screen height) at the top of a ViewController's view and have a Paged Scrollview below, where the textfield and go button is on page one, when a user clicks GO it scrolls to page two to display the information there. So you would have two UIView's, one for each page in the scrollview.

But without knowing how much information there is about a user it is virtually impossible to give a perfect answer :)

Thats my 2c.